# $\biggl( \prod_{i=1}^{+ \infty} \mathbb{Z}/2^i \mathbb{Z} \biggr)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} \neq 0$ without using $p$-adic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'm doing this exercise from Dummit-Foote:

Show that tensor products do not commute with direct products in general. [Consider
the extension of scalars from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ of the direct product of the modules $M_i = \mathbb{Z}/2^i \mathbb{Z}, \ i = 1 , 2, \ldots$ ]

Then we see that $$\prod_{i=1}^{+ \infty} \biggl( \mathbb{Z}/2^i \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} \biggr) = \prod_i 0 = 0$$

But is there a way to conclude that $$\biggl( \prod_{i=1}^{+ \infty}  \mathbb{Z}/2^i \mathbb{Z} \biggr)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} \neq 0$$

without using $p$-adic integers ?

Comment: Just give a nonzero element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

You should be able to argue that $(1,1,1,\dots)\otimes 1\ne 0$, since no rational multiple of it can be $0$.

Comment: I think your hint is based on the following fact

Comment: If $G$ is an abelian group in $G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ we have that $$x \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{b} = y \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{c} \Leftrightarrow cx = by$$

Comment: Is it correct ?

Comment: Sure, it's correct, but I guess I don't see how this is being applied.

Comment: for example $$(1,1,1, \ldots ) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{1} = 0 = 0 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{2} = (0,0,0, \ldots ) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow  2 \cdot (1,1,1, \ldots ) = (0,0,0, \ldots )$$ which is not true

Comment: OK, WLOG, I see what you're thinking. I agree. Intuitively, the idea is that $(1,1,1,\dots)\otimes 2^N = (\underbrace{0,0\dots,0}_{N\text{ times}},1,\dots) \ne 0$, so, lacking "$2^\infty$", there is nothing better to try :)